# Return a value from bootstrap's modal box yes or no option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code:

```
function ConfirmYesNo(title, msg) {
    var $confirm = $("#myModal");
    $confirm.modal('show');
    $("#myModalLabel").html(title);
    $("#myModalText").html(msg);
    $("#btnYes").off('click').click(function () {
        $confirm.modal("hide");
        return 1;
    });
    $("#btnNo").off('click').click(function () {
        $confirm.modal("hide");
        return 0;
    });
}

function ValidationWarning(WarningMsg) {
    var a = ConfirmYesNo(Warning", WarningMsg);
}
```

I want to know whether the user had pressed Yes or No button before proceeding. Using `return 1` or `return 0` does not work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Promise in jquery: [Jquery Promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)
or [deferred.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

```js
function ConfirmYesNo(title, msg) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
  var $confirm = $('#myModal');
  $confirm.modal('show');
  $('#myModalLabel').html(title);
  $('#myModalText').html(msg);
  $('#name').off('click').click(function () {
    $confirm.modal('hide');
    dfd.resolve(1);
    return 1;
  });
  $('#btnNo').off('click').click(function () {
    $confirm.modal('hide');
    return 0;
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
function ValidationWarning(WarningMsg) {
  var a = ConfirmYesNo('dddd', ' WarningMsg');
  a.then(function (b) {
    console.log(b);
    alert(b)
  })
}
ValidationWarning()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```